# Are there any noted differences in appearance rendering of html and xhtml in Google Chrome from other browsers?

Tags: html, xhtml, browser, google-chrome

Are there any noted differences in appearance rendering of HTML and XHTML in Google Chrome from Firefox? From IE? From other browsers? What browser does it render the code the most similar to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's based on WebKit, its rendering will most closely resemble Safari and Konqueror.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Chrome uses the [**WebKit rendering engine**](http://webkit.org/), which is what Safari uses. So, I would guess it renders most closely to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

There are [anti-aliasing differences](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kurafire/2822606444/) between Safari 3.1 and Google Chrome, for whatever that's worth. This will doubtless be because Safari on Windows uses its own text-rendering and anti-aliasing layer instead of Windows's GDI.

Answer (score 0):

There are additional minor differences that I have attributed to Chrome using a different (older?) version of Webkit (525.13) than the current release of Safari uses (525.21 for me).

Example:

https://woot.campfirenow.com/login

In Safari, the password label and input box are directly below the email label and input box, while in Chrome the password label and input box are indented approximately 75 pixels to the right.